# Same bar different color / One bar with many colors

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js

I have a challenge and I'm going well I need to do this chart using chartjs. I think I'm going to do 2 differents canvas, one for the 3 bars(current mo, next mo, following mo) above dashed line and another one for the 2 bars down below the dashed line(current q, next q). I'm researching the best way to do it and I appreciate your advice/help. I don't know how to set different colors to the same bar like that: blue, yellow and red for the same bar.

Thank you so much.

[image: my goal]

Comment: I answered your main question. Please start writing your own code and post a new question if you don't find the solution for another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the question from your title: "Same bar different color / One bar with many colors".

This can be done using [stacked bar chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#stacked-bar-chart).

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['CURRENT MO.', 'NEXT MO.', 'FOLLOWING MO.'],
    datasets: [{
        label: '',
        data: [1.6, 1.15, 1],
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
      },
      {
        label: 'CERTAIN',
        data: [0.15, 0.3, 0.45],
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(119, 185, 229)'
      },
      {
        label: 'EXPECTED',
        data: [0.45, 0.7, 0.6],
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(231,200,28)'
      },
      {
        label: 'UNLIKELY',
        data: [0.25, 0.35, 0.45],
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(238, 63, 55)'
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    tooltips: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          min: 0.5,
          max: 3
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridlines: {
          display: false
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: [false, true, true, true]
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Where Are We Going to Land?'
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="140"></canvas>
```

Comment: Love you my boss !